# Laravel Component Do not Pass Variables to Blade

Tags: php, laravel

I have a component that I want to pass if button [true] then it shows. However it does not pass to the blade.

Component Usage

Default would be set as false in the component file, so I just pass whenever it sets as false [or to hide it]

```
<x-invoice.invoice-list :invoice="$item"></x-invoice.invoice-list>
```

Component File

```
class InvoiceList extends Component
{
    public UserInvoice $invoice;
    public $button;
    /**
     * Create a new component instance.
     */
    public function __construct($invoice,$button = true)
    {
        $this->invoice = $invoice;
        $this->button = $button;
    }

    /**
     * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
     */
    public function render(): View|Closure|string
    {
        return view('components.invoice.invoice-list');
    }
}
```

Component blade file

```
<div class="p-2 border border-gray-200 rounded-xl mb-3 text-center relative col-span-12 lg:col-span-6">
    <div class="p-2 bg-black text-white rounded-xl font-bold text-xl mt-10">{{ format_currency($invoice->total) }}</div>
    <div class="p-2 absolute top-0 right-0 me-2 capitalize">
        <x-shared.listing-invoice-status-box :invoice="$invoice">{{ $invoice->status }}</x-shared.listing-invoice-status-box>
    </div>
    <div class="p-2 text-center font-bold">{{ __('Order List') }}</div>
    <div class="p-2 border border-orange-100 rounded-xl bg-orange-50">
        @foreach ($invoice->order as $order)
            <x-shared.order-list :$order></x-shared.order-list>
        @endforeach
    </div>
    @if ($button and $invoice->status=='pending')
        <x-button.pay wire:click="$dispatch('openModal',{component:'modal.modal-invoice-do-payment',arguments:{'userInvoice':{{$invoice->id}}}})" class="mt-5 mb-2">{{__('Pay')}} <i
                class="ps-2 fa-solid fa-circle-right"></i></x-button.pay>
    @endif
</div>
```

Actually, it runs normally in localhost but whenever I deploy to server it causes

> Undefined variable $button

Comment: You're missing `{{` and `}}` around the variables.

Answer (score -1):

You can clear Laravel cache

```
php artisan cache:clear
```